# react CRA - exclude debug code from build

Tags: reactjs, optimization, production-environment, dead-code, react-loadable

Is there any method to completely exclude some code from if statements in production mode??

I was trying to do something like that:

```
import React from "react";
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

function Loading() {
  return <div></div>;
}

let LoadableDebugBar;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  LoadableDebug = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./Debug'),
    loading: Loading
  });
} else{
  LoadableDebug = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./BlankComponent'),
    loading: Loading
  });
}

export default LoadableDebug;
```

The problem is that when App is built you can still see source code from debug component idea is to strip it completely because in production mode Component is never in usage.

Even if I lazyload it still not satisfy me because i want to completely get rid of it so I can hide all debug features.

Answer (score 2):

Solved that with this way: inside my build code there is no debug component anymore.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
let DebugBarContainer;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  DebugBarContainer = require('../../containers/DebugBarContainer').default;
} else {
  DebugBarContainer = () => null;
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <DebugBarContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```